# When should I use `<>` instead of `~~` to join two strings?

Tags: string-manipulation

Both `<>`, i.e. `StringJoin` and `~~`, i.e. `StringExpression`, can be used to join two strings. I know that only the latter can be used to describe a string pattern (instead of joining actual strings). Are there other situations when only `<>` is appropriate? Or can I always use `~~`?

Comment: `StringJoin` ignores list structure, so it's a bit more convenient if patterns are not involved, IMO. It's also a bit faster.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my opinion, if you want to join strings, the choice between `<>` and `~~` is clear: [`StringJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) is explicitly intended to join strings. [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) is not, it just happens to do so in many contexts in the current version, as it facilitates pattern matching.

The documentation makes no promise that `StringExpression` should work for the purpose of joining strings, so why would want to use it for that at all, especially when there is a different operator which is specifically for joining strings? I think that even if `StringExpression` always joins strings in the current version (I am not aware of cases when it doesn't), Wolfram would be completely justified in changing this behaviour in the future if it helps improve string pattern matching.

---

So, to sum up:

> When should I use `<>` instead of `~~` to join two strings?

*Always.* Use functions for their intended purpose, not for things that they happen to do by accident, but give no guarantees for.

---

Differences in the current behaviour of `StringJoin` and `StingExpression`:

As @ciao points out in a comment, `StringJoin` works on (nested) lists of strings, while `StringExpression` does not.

He also mentions that `StringJoin` may be faster, so I did a quick benchmark. I could not find any speed difference between the two, but the fact that `StingJoin` can be used on lists does give it a *practical* performance advantage, as one can avoid the overhead from `Apply`.

```
SeedRandom[12345];
list = RandomWord[1000000];

Table[StringJoin[list]; // RepeatedTiming // First, 5]
(* {0.0266891, 0.0262008, 0.0269283, 0.0270262, 0.0266054} *)

Table[StringJoin @@ list; // RepeatedTiming // First, 5]
(* {0.0451839, 0.0451968, 0.045871, 0.0447449, 0.0457315} *)

Table[StringExpression @@ list; // RepeatedTiming // First, 5]
(* {0.0454046, 0.0450875, 0.0447029, 0.0453249, 0.0450471} *)
```

Comment: Also you can count on `StringJoin` issuing a message when given a non-string.

Comment: A comment for people participating in [Wolfram Challenges](https://challenges.wolframcloud.com/): To get the lowest _code characters_ score, you have to use `~~` instead of `<>`, because the `InputForm` (which is what the scoring system measures) of `~~` is just `~~`, while `<>` gets converted to `StringJoin[...]`.

Comment: @Domen Worth a separate answer?